# Cannot start up rails server or rails console

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails project. I run command `rails server` and `rails console`, but both give me this error:

[image]

So, I ran the command `sudo gem install polyglot`. It successfully installed polyglot-0.3.5, but the same error still persists. I am wondering what the problem is. Is there anything wrong in my Gemfile?

My Rails version is "Rails 5.0.0.1" and my Ruby version is "ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]".

Comment: What happens if you start the server with: `bundle exec rails server`

Comment: i've just created a rails 5 app, and installed polyglot gem. everything is ok. better try with any ruby version manager (rbenv, rvm etc.).

Comment: @ReggieB I tried `bundle exec rails server`, but it produces the same error.

Comment: @marmeladze I am using rbenv, all the installations for gems worked fine (including the `polyglot` gem), but I just can't start the server or do anything related to the `rails` command. And the error says there is something wrong in the polyglot

Comment: @Jeffrey Yong, does your bundle install run without error ?
What your log says exactly is, that your polyglot gem tries to load astrolobe, and the loading of this fails. So it has not directly to do with the installation. But the installation of polyglot should make sure there is everything it needs.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I bundle install runs without error. I can even see `Using polyglot 0.3.5`. But I still can't start rails with the same error as before.

Comment: Does your setting run without the polyglot gem ? I saw the last polyglot release was 2014 where your ruby version is from 04/16 could be incompatible. Maybe try an older ruby version ? If you can nail the error to polyglot write an issue on the github page. https://github.com/cjheath/polyglot/issues

Comment: What happens if you add this to your Gemfile: `gem 'astrolabe'`

Comment: Hey guys, thanks so much for your help. I now start my Gemfile from scratch and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You should add in Gemfile this line `gem 'polyglot'` , then run bundle install. It will be better to add gem locally in Gemfile instead globally through gem install.

Comment: Hi I added gem 'polyglot' in my `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: have you added `gem 'astrolabe'` in Gemfile ?